# Unity. Package signatures do not match previously installed version; ignoring

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play

Faced the following problem:
With the next update of the game in Google Play, APK files from the unit were no longer installed on the phone. The console writes that the signatures do not match.(For some reason twice)
[Debug Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtNni.jpg)

However, I checked the signatures of the aab file uploaded to the store and the apk file of the next version generated in Unity. They match perfectly!
[apksigner sreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qb67S.jpg)
[keytool screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2DXg.jpg)

What could be the reason and how to solve the problem? I say right away that deleting the installed version is not an option, since I need to check the safety of user data during the update.
I also tried to form, without changing anything in the player settings, aab file followed by apk. I uploaded aab to the store, downloaded it and tried to install the apk on top of it through the unity. The result is the same.

Comment: Does the play store use your provided signing key to re-sign the APKs it generates from the AAB or did you leave the default settings and allowed the play store to create an own key?

Comment: @Alexander Hoffmann, Allowed the store to generate its own key. I already thought that this was the reason, but before it worked with the same settings ... That is, it seems that earlier when installing the apk from Unity, the difference in certificates was ignored. Could this be some setting in Unity or the android device?

Comment: @alexander-hoffmann, Allowed the store to generate its own key. I already thought that this was the reason, but before it worked with the same settings ... That is, it seems that earlier when installing the apk from Unity, the difference in certificates was ignored. Could this be some setting in Unity or the android device?

Comment: This can't be a changed setting. It is never possible to install an update for an app that has the same package name but a different signature. Period. Android will show an error in that case. Just to be sure, compare your signatures with the one that google Play Console uses. In the Play Store console, open your app, go to Setup-App Integrity -> App signing and check the signature.

Comment: @Alexander Hoffmann, The signature of the apk from Unity matches the signature of the aab uploaded to the store, but does not match the signature of the final apk, which is unzipped on the Google side from aab and offered for download to users.

Comment: Then we found the error and unfortunatelly there isn't anything you can do about it. Google generated an own signing key when Play Store signing was enabled. Your signing key is now only an "upload key" and used to prove to Google that you're the original developer. The Play Store re signs the APKs with its own key.

Comment: @Alexander Hoffmann, Now it's clear. Thanks a lot for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

somehow your old application is not removed 100% or its data is not removed.

```
adb uninstall "com.company.appname"
```

If you don't know exactly what to put as replacement for "com.company.appname", then you just open Android studio, Run your app while it is connected to a device and then look at Debug window.

Comment: I have no problems with a clean install of the application. I need to install a fresh build from unity over the version downloaded from the store to check the compatibility of the saved data. This has never been a problem before...